# "char not expected" error when compiling in MINIX

Tags: c, cc, minix

I need to print a line to the screen and then  get user input, but the `printf("blah")` statements cause my code to not compile. The error message says 'char not expected" but when I comment the `printf()` statements out, then the code compile.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(void) 
{ 
    printf("Welcome to the shell!\n"); 
    printf("shell:>");
    char* inp = (char*)malloc(20); // error at this line
}
```

I am using the cc compiler in MINIX 3.1.0

Comment: Please [see why not to cast](http://stackoverflow.com/q/605845/2173917) the return value of `malloc()` and family in `C`.

Comment: And include `stdlib.h` and don't forget to free the allocated memory.

Comment: It was included in my original program, I added it here just now. Tfree the memory later in the program. :-) I will check the malloc() link now. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The MINIX C compiler is not following modern standards, which means that local variables can only be declared at the start of functions.

You need to do e.g.

```
char *inp;

printf("Welcome to the shell!\n"); 
printf("shell:>");

inp = malloc(20);
```

---

When I say "modern" I mean the C99 standard. The older C89 standard, which the MINIX compiler seems to follow, and also the Visual Studio C compiler until recently (much of C99 wasn't supported until VS2013 and later), only allowed declarations at the beginning of blocks.

Comment: That worked! Thanks. I was completely unaware that it used to work like that.

Comment: For a *good* answer, one should point out which revision of the standard introduced the "modern" feature.  (The feature in some other languages predated c89).